# What is does the regular expression /^\s*$/ do?

Tags: regex, perl

What does this expression in Perl programming do?

```
$variable =~ /^\s*$/;
```

Answer (score 23, accepted):

That's looking for a line start (^), followed by zero or more whitespace (\s*) characters, followed by a line end ($).

It's essentially looking for blank/empty lines.

I'd expect the expression to be used in something like:

```
if ($v =~ /^\s*$/) {
   # found a blank line
}
```

in order to perform the check and a following action.

Comment: The phrase "any number" is a little vague, I would say zero or more whitespace characters instead.

Answer (score 1):

Nothing, since you are not assigning the result of this operation to any variable, and since it has no side effects that you are likely to test for.

However, if you said

```
if ($variable =~ /^\s*$/)
{
  print "something";
}
```

You would be answering the question:

Does the value in variable consist of an empty line or a line consisting of nothing but non printing whitespace characters such as spaces and tabs?

Comment: true alex,the actual statement is in a loop which reads data from the file and has the condition 

next if ($variable =~ /^\s*$/);

Comment: In that case, it means

"skip blank lines in the file"

Comment: Alex, technically it's not entirely correct. Regex search in Perl has a number of side effects, even if you don't assign the result to any variable. For example, the $& variable holds the last match, so, one can use it on the next line, like this: if (defined $&) { ... }

Comment: While you are correct that $& holds the value of the last match, it does not hold undef if that match failed.  For example:

  perl -e 'alex=~/alex/;joe=~/swapnil/;print $&'

Prints "alex", since that was the last successful match.

Answer (score 1):

`=~` is a match operator.

The statement returns true if $variable only consists of spaces, or is simply empty.

So it just checks if the string is empty or not.

Answer (score 1):

```
 if ( $variable =~ /^\s*$/ )
```

is the same as

```
 unless ( $variable =~ /\S/ )
```

or

```
 if ( $variable !~ /\S/ )
```